# How do you change the position of extensions in top bar?

Tags: gnome, top-bar

I've seen this feature in KDE plasma, but I was wondering if I could move the gnome extensions position on the top bar. If this isn't possible, is there a way to load extensions asynchronously so that I could coax gnome to order my icons? I'm asking this because I saw an extension named [Freon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/) which allowed me to customize it's position, so I know that there might be a chance its possible. I'm on GNOME Shell 3.38.1

Comment: Yes, the problem is the extension only customizes it's own position on the top panel.